# How to correctly import @nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers into hardhat project?

Tags: typescript, chai, ethers.js, hardhat

Following [the instructions](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-chai-matchers/docs/overview),
I put this in `hardhat.config.ts`:

```
import '@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers';
```

In my test I have:

```
expect(maxCount).to.equal(64);
```

where `maxCount` is a BigNumber from ethers.js, and `64` is a regular Javascript/Typescript number.... but I get this error:

```
AssertionError: expected [ BigNumber { value: "64" } ] to equal 64
```

... which means that the hardhat chai matcher is not kicking in,
as it is supposed to handle the BigNumber by performing
the conversion automatically as part of the assertion.

This leads me to think that the way I'm importing this module may be incorrect.
What's the proper way?

Technically, the ["Usage" section](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/plugins/nomicfoundation-hardhat-chai-matchers#usage)
of the docs state it as a CommonJS `require`:

```js
require("@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers");
```

Since my hardhat config (and rest of project) is in Typescript,
I've used this instead:

```
import '@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers';
```

---

More details:

Here're my dev dependencies from `package.json`:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers": "1.0.6",
    "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox": "2.0.2",
    "@types/chai": "4.3.4",
    "@types/fs-extra": "11.0.1",
    "@types/mocha": "10.0.1",
    "@types/node": "18.14.6",
    "fs-extra": "11.1.0",
    "hardhat": "2.13.0",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "typescript": "4.9.5"
  }
```

And here're my run times:

```
$ node -v
v16.13.1
$ npm -v
8.1.2
```

---

**Edit**

In an attempt to debug, I've manually edited
`node_modules/@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers/src/internal/bigNumber.ts`
to add `console.log` statements in a couple of spots.

```
function overwriteBigNumberFunction(
  functionName: Methods,
  readableName: string,
  readableNegativeName: string,
  _super: (...args: any[]) => any,
  chaiUtils: Chai.ChaiUtils
) {
  console.log('hh chai matcher overwriteBigNumberFunction');
  /* ... */
```

```
    } else if (isBigNumber(expectedFlag) || isBigNumber(actualArg)) {
      console.log('hh chai matcher bignit');
  /* ... */
```

Then subsequently run `npx hardhat console`.
Neither of the above log statements are output,
leading me further to believe that the way I'm importing isn't right.

Comment: Looks like it was nothing to do with the way it was imported, rather it was something unrelated - answered separately here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75681555/194982