# In ethers.js, why does the return value of a function return an array containing the value instead of the value?

Tags: typescript, solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, rootstock

The assertion for the following test fails:

```
    it('should access MAX_COUNT', async () => {
        const maxCount = await myContract.functions.MAX_COUNT();
        expect(maxCount).to.equal(64);
    });
```

With the following error:

```
AssertionError: expected [ BigNumber { value: "64" } ] to equal 64
```

This is the solidity code for (the concise version of) the smart contract being tested:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
pragma solidity 0.8.17;

contract MyContract
{
    uint256 public constant MAX_COUNT = 64;
}
```

Why is the return value `[ BigNumber { value: "64" } ]` instead of just `BigNumber { value: "64" }`?

---

For context, this question was originally created while trying to figure out this one:
[How to correctly import `@nomicfoundation/hardhat-chai-matchers` into hardhat project?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75680103/194982) ...
However turns out to be completely unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This test should fail:

```
    it('should access MAX_COUNT', async () => {
        const maxCount = await multiSend.functions.MAX_COUNT();
        expect(maxCount).to.equal(64);
    });
```

However, this should pass:

```
    it('should access MAX_COUNT', async () => {
        const maxCount = await multiSend.MAX_COUNT();
        expect(maxCount).to.equal(64);
    });
```

And this test should pass too:

```
    it('should access MAX_COUNT', async () => {
        const [maxCount] = await multiSend.functions.MAX_COUNT();
        expect(maxCount).to.equal(64);
    });
```

The clue is in the documentation,
specifically the difference between the return types
when called via `Contract.functions.XYZ()` vs `Contract.XYZ()`:

[docs for `Contract.functions` call](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/contract/contract/#Contract-functionsCall)

In summary `Contract.XYZ()` returns either `Promise< any >` or `Promise< Result >`;
whereas `Contract.functions.XYZ()` always returns `Promise< Result >`

[docs for `Result` return type](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/utils/abi/interface/#Result)

The `Result` object is designed for functions that can return multiple values etc, so that's why it it needs to be array-destructured.